# How can I reduce time to finish (For loop) to compare two Excel columns using C# as below code :

Tags: c#, excel

in case rows count is more than 100 rows this code takes very long time sometimes more than hours , is there any other method to reduce the time ?

```
for (int i = 2; i < ws5.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int n = 2; n < ws6.UsedRange.Rows.Count; n++)
    {
        if(Convert.ToDouble(ws5.Cells[i, 3].Value) == Convert.ToDouble(ws6.Cells[n, 3].Value) 
            && Convert.ToString(ws5.Cells[i, 2].Value) == Convert.ToString(ws6.Cells[n, 2].Value))
        {
            ws5.Cells[i, 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
            ws5.Cells[i, 3].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
            ws6.Cells[n, 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
            ws6.Cells[n, 3].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDouble(ws5.Cells[i, 3].Value) != Convert.ToDouble(ws6.Cells[n, 3].Value) 
            && Convert.ToString(ws5.Cells[i, 2].Value) == Convert.ToString(ws6.Cells[n, 2].Value))
        {
            ws5.Cells[i, 4].Value = Convert.ToDouble(ws6.Cells[n, 3].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(ws5.Cells[i, 3].Value) ;
            ws6.Cells[n, 4].Value = Convert.ToDouble(ws5.Cells[i, 3].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(ws6.Cells[n, 3].Value) ;

            ws5.Cells[i, 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
            ws5.Cells[i, 3].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
            ws6.Cells[n, 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
            ws6.Cells[n, 3].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
        
        }
        progressBar1.Value = (100 * i) / (ws5.UsedRange.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not going into the details of what you are trying to acheive with excel, instead of doing the loop inside of another loop (that's O(n^2) time complexity), create a dictionary <string,money>, such that you can look up invoice amounts based on invoice numbers, and then go through the 2nd spreadsheet, checking if you have the same value(s) in your dictionary. That wasy you reduce time complexity to O(2n)

Comment: Thanks I used dictionary and now my code is very fast .